# Missing method excpetion with Socket on Windows Emedded Compact

Tags: nanoframework

Following simple code:

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

results in missing method exception on Windows Embedded Compact 2013.

Any idea what can be that wrong?

Best regards:
Stoyan

Answer (score 0):

If you're using System.Net class library for .NET nanoFramework that's expected because isn't meant to on Windows Embedded systems, only on devices running .NET nanoFramework CLR.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes I am using System.Net class library for .NET nanoFramework. So how can I get it working on Windows Embedded systems? All I want to achieve is get https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite working on embedded compact as it said it is tested on that OS?

Comment: You can't use the nanoFramework DLL on Windows Embedded. It won't work. Sugest that you try to find the AMQP Lite Nuget for that version. Perhaps you can also ask on their github repo.